# Get-IISAppPool returns less results in VSCode than actual number

Tags: powershell, iis, visual-studio-code, web-administration

I have 80 application pools in my local machine, Windows 10 Enterprise.
Get-IISAppPool in Powershell ISE returns 80 pools.
Get-IISAppPool in Visual Studio Code returns only 5 pools.
Recycling IIS does not change the results.

```
$pools = Get-IISAppPool
"pools.Count: " + $pools.Count

pools.Count: 5
```

However, inside VSCode's Powershell Integrated Shell, 
PS IIS:\AppPools> dir
returns the 80 application pools

Edit:  From VSCode done a different way, returns the expected 80.

```
$pools = Get-ChildItem -Path "IIS:\AppPools"
"pools.Count: " + $pools.Count

pools.Count: 80
```

I'm not seeing anything on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool?view=win10-ps indicating when I should receive a partial result set, so in which direction should I be troubleshooting?

Comment: As it does not seem to be reproducible, you'd better open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com so that Microsoft guys might check your machine.

Comment: Just off chance - you aren't accidentally using PSRemote and connecting to another machine, thus giving you the diff # app pools?

Comment: @Russell correct. In fact the 5 pools returned are the first 5 pools returned of the 80.

Answer (score 1):

Repro'ed - The PowerShell Get-IISAppPool command does not update the list of returned Application Pools.

Get-IISAppPool returned the same list of application pools regardless of adding addition application pools via the IIS management console.

To work around this issue I started a new PowerShell CLI and Get-IISAppPool must have updated because it returned the correct list of results. HTH

Comment: There's a similar solution here: [Odd issue when using Get-IISAppPool and creating a new app pool in the same session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660077/1144952)