# Odd issue when using Get-IISAppPool and creating a new app pool in the same session

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm writing up a script to create a new app pool if an app pool I'm passing in does not exist.  When the pool is created and I run Get-IISAppPool in the same session, the new app pool does not exist.

Here's how to duplicate it.

```
New-WebAppPool -Name "Test"
Get-IISAppPool
```

It will not show the new one that was created.

If you open up a new shell and run Get-IISAppPool, you'll see the new app pool.

Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows Server 2016 and PowerShell 5.1. Can you tell us more about your environment? I can replicate the issue if I add more than a second pool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For better or for worse, I was able to reliably see the new app pool consistently this way:

```
New-WebAppPool -Name "Test"
Reset-IISServerManager
Get-IISAppPool
```

This seems like a weird bug. As a workaround, you could also do the following if you don't need the output types to be Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool

```
import-module WebAdministration # this is only necessary if you don't execute WebAdministration module cmdlets before the GCI command

New-WebAppPool -Name "Test"
get-childitem IIS:\AppPools
```

Comment: gci IIS: will not work unless you have the webadministration module loaded. If you are running the new-webapppool command, then it will automatically be loaded.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Still seems odd that I had to do this but I'll take it.

Comment: It's actually (somewhat) documentated behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/powershell/module/iisadministration/reset-iisservermanager?view=win10-ps states "The Reset-IISServerManager cmdlet resets the IISAdministration view of the IIS ServerManager object and the view of .config file applicationHost.config to the current contents of the .config file."