# Powershell adds duplicate IIS Application Pool

Tags: powershell, iis

I have the below Powershell script to create an Application Pool and a Website in IIS. The script adds the App Pool the first time I run it (when the App Pool does not exist) however when I run the script for the second time, although the App Pool exists, the script does not find it and tries to create it again. Leading to an Exception!

```
$WebsiteName="search-api"
$AppPoolName="search-api"
$Runtime=""   # Empty = Not Managed
$Port = 3050
$PhysicalPath="C:\Applications\SearchApi"

import-module WebAdministration

clear

New-Item -Path $PhysicalPath -Force

$AppPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $AppPoolName

If ($AppPool.Length -eq 0)
{ 
    $AppPool = New-WebAppPool -Name $AppPoolName -Force 
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $Runtime
}


$TheWebSite = Get-Website -Name $WebsiteName

If ($TheWebSite -eq $null)
{
    New-Website -Name $WebsiteName -Port $Port -IPAddress "*" -ApplicationPool $AppPoolName -PhysicalPath  $PhysicalPath -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st**: avoid *PropertyNotFoundException*:

```
If ( $AppPool.Length -eq 0 ) {  }
```

> The property 'Length' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

Use `If ( $null -eq $AppPool ) {  }` instead.

**2nd**: Read *[AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)*' answer to [*Odd issue when using Get-IISAppPool and creating a new app pool in the same session*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660077/3439404).

Either apply `Reset-IISServerManager` (might require confirmation),

or, instead of `Get-IISAppPool -Name $AppPoolName`, use

```
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where-Object Name -eq $AppPoolName
```

**3rd**: [`New-WebSite` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/new-website?view=win10-ps) says about the `-PhysicalPath` parameter:

> Specifies the physical path of the new site. The specified **folder**
>   must already exist.

Use `New-Item -Path $PhysicalPath -Force -ItemType Directory`

Answer (score 0):

You could try below script to create a site in iis:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisAppPoolName = "my-test-app"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"
$iisAppName = "mytest"
$directoryPath = "C:\s2"

#navigate to the app pools root
cd IIS:\AppPools\

#check if the app pool exists
if (!(Test-Path $iisAppPoolName -pathType container))
{
    #create the app pool
    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
}

#navigate to the root of the site
cd IIS:\Sites\

#check if the site exists
if (Test-Path $iisAppName -pathType container)
{
    return
}

#create the site
$iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":87:"} -physicalPath $directoryPath
$iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value $iisAppPoolName
```

[image]